# Derived class calls an inherited function that uses non-inherited members

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

I have a base class that has two private variables, and a public method to print them. By inheriting from it, I get a method that uses variables that aren't inherited to the derived class. However, it works and calls that method with the values given by base class constructor.

Even by adding to derived his own default constructor, and the same int x, y; variables, with different default values, the method prints the base class default ones. Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it? I'm aware of protected members but still what's happening here? I first tried this with derived class empty (without constructor and variables) and the result is the same. How can it use variables that are not inherited?

```cpp
class base {
private:
    int x, y;

public:
    base(int px=1, int py=2)
        :x(px), y(py)
    {}

    inline void print() const {
        cout << x << ", " << y << '\n';
    }
};

class derived : public base {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    derived(int px = 3, int py = 3)
        :x(px), y(py)
    {}
};

int main{
        derived e;
        e.print(); // prints 1, 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base::print` cannot see member variables in `derived`.  You have a few options:

1. Use `protected` if you actually want `base::x` and `derived::x` to be different.
2. Pass `px` and `py` to `base`'s constructor: `derived(int px = 3, int py = 3) : base(px, py) { }`
3. Make `base::print` a `virtual` member function and override it in `derived`.

Which option is best depends on your requirements.

Comment: I just copied base::print to derived without making it virtual and it worked...

Comment: @Denomycor - You're going to run into trouble if somebody has a pointer or reference to a `base` and calls `print`.  You really want to make it `virtual`.